# CSS3 Fade In Instead of Sliding?

Tags: css

Heres my CSS:

```
#display {
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
    -moz-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -o-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#display:hover{
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 -49px;
}
```

with #display as the ID of an anchor when I hover over it instead of fading into the sprite 49 pixels below it slides to it.. anyway to get it to fade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pure CSS way of doing this would be as follows:

```
#display {
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
}

#display:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 -49px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
        opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
   -moz-transition-property: opacity;
     -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity;
        transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
     -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#display:after:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What this code does is use the CSS3 :after pseudo element to basically create a brand new image on top, and then fade that from transparent to opaque when it is hovered over.

The only problem is that Firefox is currently the only browser that supports fading :before and :after pseudo elements.

If you have a child element inside (like a div or a element), you could do this instead:

```
#display {
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
}

#display a {
    display: block;
    background: url('/src/images/icons/display.png') no-repeat 0 -49px;
    height: 49px;
    width: 49px;
    float: left;
        opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
   -moz-transition-property: opacity;
     -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: opacity;
        transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
     -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#display:hover a {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but it *reads* like you're asking for help with fading a colour change? If that's so:

```
#test {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -kthml-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    transition:  background-color 2s linear;
}
#test:hover {
    background-color: #f90;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    -kthml-transition: background-color 2s linear;
    transition:  background-color 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3svDq/1/).

On the other hand, if you want it to fade the element in:

```
#test {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -kthml-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition:  opacity 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
#test:hover {
    background-color: #f90;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    -kthml-transition: opacity 2s linear;
    transition:  opacity 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3svDq/2/).

Comment: the background image is sprite.. so it had the icon in red and also in white.. by default its red and i would want the white icon to fade in when the image is hovered over.. maybe im doin it the wrong way?

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), and use the actual image sprite?